# How are 2d arrays structured?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

When I was taught 2d arrays, I was taught that they are arrays of arrays, similar to an array of ArrayLists. But I was thinking about it and it is actually really confusing:

```
ArrayList[] arrOfList = new ArrayList[5];
arrOfList[0] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
arrOfList[0].add(1);
arrOfList[0].add(2);
arrOfList[0].add(3);
//arrOfList[0] is the first list, with 3 elements
//arrOfList is an array of 5 lists; arrOfList.length = 5

int[][] arrOfArr = new int[3][5];
//arrOfArr[0] is NOT an array with 3 elements
//arrOfArr is NOT an array of 5 arrays; arrOfArr.length = 3
```

I think what I'm getting at is more clear if I bold the parts that I think would correlate (but don't):

**ArrayList**[] arrOfList = new **ArrayList**[5];
**int[]**[] arrOfArr = new **int[3]**[5];

What is a more intuitive way of thinking about declaring 2d arrays, since relating it to an arbitrary type is not right? (as illustrated above)

Comment: watch this, then it will be clear to you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVJ7kpEMc7U

Comment: im familiar with both data types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

This may help you visualize it more.

When using square brackets `[]`, first pair is always row, second pair is columns.
In both scenarios, the first dimension (row) saves the memory address of the corresponding Array / ArrayLists.

The second dimension (column) saves the corresponding value stored in that particular row of Array/ArrayList.

What you are taught is correct. An array of arrays is similar to an array of arraylists, with the exception that arraylists have variable length. The implication is that with an array of arraylists, the width (no. of columns) isn't static.

```
ArrayList[] arrOfList = new ArrayList[5]
```

This is saying, create an **Array of length 5** (5 rows), with the *data type being ArrayList (of variable length, thus can be any number of columns)*.

```
int[][] arrOfArr = new int[3][5]
```

This is saying, create an **Array of length 3 (3 rows)**, with the *data type being Array with length 5 (5 columns)*.

The fact that an ArrayList has variable length is likely causing the confusion, but I still stand by the same answer: first pair of [] = row; second pair of [] = column.

Answer (score 0):

`int[][] arrOfArr = new int[3][5]`

That creates an empty *grid* of array cells with 3 rows and 5 columns. i.e.

```
[][][][][]
[][][][][]
[][][][][]
```

Then to fill those columns you just do `arrOfArr[0][2] = 4` which goes down to `row 0` and across to `column 2`. i.e.

```
[][][4][][]
[][][][][]
[][][][][]
```

---

Alternatively, see it as a set of 3 lots of 5 cell arrays

```
[][][4][][], [][][][][], [][][][][]
```

Answer (score -1):

int[][] arrOfArr = new int[3][5];

//arrOfArr[3] is the number of rows
//arrOfArr[5] is the number of colums

Comment: uh no? they are both out of bounds and will throw exceptions

Comment: this answer is still relevant nonetheless. when declaring a 2D array, the first argument denotes the length of the row; the second the length of the column.

As such, you can think of ArrayList[5] as a 5x1 matrix, similar to how a 2D int matrix looks like when you declare int[5][1].

Comment: yeah exactly, i was thinking that that is confusing because you would think new int[5][1] is more similar to new ArrayList[1] (populated with 5 elements) but it is not

Comment: I think you are confused because of the usage of an ArrayList as the Array element type. Fundamentally, it is the same regardless of what kind of data type you are storing in the array. I think you just need to remember this: whenever you're using a square bracket to initialize an array, the first pair will always denote the row.